# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

I have the following JPA class .

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the ACCOUNT database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@XmlID
@Column(name="ACCOUNT_NO", unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
private String accountNo;
```

`

I am using EJB to fetch matching accounts .

```
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class Account
 */
@Stateless
public class AccountBean implements AccountRemote {

@Override
    public List<Account> searchAccount(String searchKeyword) {
        TypedQuery<Account> query = entityManager.createQuery(" select a from " + Account.class.getName() +"  a where a.ACCOUNT_NO LIKE :searchKeyword ",Account.class);
        query.setParameter("searchKeyword", "%"+searchKeyword+"%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

I am trying to do a partial search for account_no .
I am a newbie to hibernate and jpa .

Refer the full stack trace below .

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ACCOUNT_NO of: model.Account [ select a from model.Account  a where a.ACCOUNT_NO LIKE :searchKeyword ]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1968) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:313) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:490) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:616) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:267) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:214) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:115) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:882) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1264) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4426) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4042) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2076) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:250) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1784) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:301) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
... 85 more
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you must use attribute name of your class instead of column name when you are using entity manager.

```
("select a from " + Account.class.getName() +"  a where a.ACCOUNT_NO LIKE :searchKeyword ", Account.class)
```

to

```
("select a from " + Account.class.getName() +"  a where a.accountNo LIKE :searchKeyword ", Account.class)
```